# Laravel queries - select entries conditionally

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a query where entries in the database may have the `end` date set to zero. How can I do the following query - I want to select all those events where:

a) the start date is before today, but the end date is set to zero (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`)

AND

b) the start date **and** the end date are after today

All I've got so far is to select where the start date after today:

```
$eventsList = DB::table('events')
    ->where('start', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->get();
```

But this misses those that started yesterday but don't have an end date set.

Edit: I have added to the query with an `orWhere` clause, but the `orWhere` causes it to return no results:

```
$eventsList = DB::table('events')
    ->where('start', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->orWhere(function($query)
  {
      $query->where('start', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->where('end', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
  })
    ->get();
```

Comment: the `where()` method is chainable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#PHP). Chain multiple `where()`'s to `AND` your conditions.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Thanks for the comment - I've still got issues with this chaining (see edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
        DB::table('events')
        ->where(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('start', '>', Carbon::now())
                  ->where('end', '>', Carbon::now())
        }
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('start', '<', Carbon::now())
                  ->where('end', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
        })
        ->get();
```